# Mocking Services in Jasmine - Inner Arguments

Tags: angular, jasmine

I am running some simple tests for a component I have written in my Angular application and had a question about spies.

Currently, I have a method that looks like the following:

```
this.serviceA.methodA(this.serviceB.methodB());
```

I was under the impression that by me spying on `this.serviceA.methodA`, I would be able to successfully mock the call and continue my tests, but it looks like it is still trying to execute the arguments.

I suspect that this might be happening because although I am spying on my outer method when the code is being read, it will first try and execute the arguments before trying to execute the outer method.

In this case, if I have some complex expression as part of my arguments, instead of constant values, do I need to mock both methods?

Thanks

Comment: I'm a bit confused by your syntax - as you wrote it above you will pass `this.serviceB.methodB` as a function parameter into `serviceA.methodA`, it will not get executed until it is called from within `serviceA.methodA`.  If you had written `this.serviceA.methodA(this.serviceB.methodB())`, then the second method would be evaluated and it's return value would be passed into the first.

Comment: @dmcgrandle, Apologies. I did mean to write it in the way that you proposed. Will correct the typo now.

Comment: That makes more sense, thank you.  :)  In this case yes - you will need to mock both `serviceA.methodA` as well as `serviceB.methodB` since both will be called.  If you need help with the mocking or are running into some sort of error, post your code and/or error(s).